# Why does PHP compact() use strings instead of actual variables?

Tags: php

Can anyone explain the benefit of PHP's [compact()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function accepting the string of 'a variable with that name' instead of the actual variable?

For example:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

$compacted = compact('foo', 'bar');
```

Why do I need to pass a string of the variable name instead of just passing the variable itself and PHP handling mapping this to an array? Like so:

```
$compacted = compact($foo, $bar);
```

Comment: How would the `compact()` function know the names of the variables if all it received were values?

Comment: in all seriousness, I would avoid using the `compact` and `extract` functions entirely. They were designed in a world when everyone wrote all their code using global variables and the `register_globals` flag was considered a good idea. These days, there really isn't any reason to use these functions if you're writing good quality code.

Comment: Thanks @cdhowie - that does answer the question.

Comment: @spudley `extract` is actually quite useful when you're processing binary data structures using `unpack`.

Comment: @cleong - If the variable is available in an array anyway, I don't see much to be gained from moving it from there into a named variable. But I've not done much work with `unpack` so I'll take your word for it that it might be a use-case where it makes sense.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because the `compact()` function needs to know the *names* of the variables since it is going to be using them as array keys.  If you passed the variables directly then `compact()` would not know their names, and would not have any value to use for the returned array keys.

However, I suggest building the array manually:

```
$arr = array(
    'foo' => $foo,
    'bar' => $bar);
```

I consider `compact()` deprecated and would avoid using it in any new code.

Comment: From where you see/consider that compact() is deprecated?

Comment: @SazzadHossainKhan It's not documented to be deprecated, rather I consider it to be deprecated -- I would not use it in any new code and I would reject any code review that makes use of it. Referencing variables in the current lexical scope by a string value is IMO very dangerous and error-prone. There are other alternatives that are more flexible than `compact()` as well as less dangerous.

Comment: @cdhowie It's been useful for me so far for collecting data for output, e.g. compact() multiple variables then json_encode() it into one response. Would you recommend an "other alternative" in this case?

Comment: @Unnawut as suggested, build the array manually. Functions like `compact()` make it difficult for someone else (or a future version of yourself) to read your code because it's not immediately obvious what's going on.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm totally with you, in my mind I also consider it deprecated :)

Comment: FWIW, compact() is heavily used in Laravel 5, and is pretty much the PHP equivalent of the still-relatively-recent ES6 destructuring object assignment ; so it seems the pattern it represents is rather popular these days.

Comment: `compact` is antipattern

Comment: @FGM if it's heavily used in Laravel, it's probably an antipatern.

Answer (score 38):

As far as benefits, I've found compact() to be useful in MVC applications. If you're writing controller code and you need to pass an associative array of variables and their apparent names that you've set in your controller to the view, it shortens something like:

```
View::make('home')->with(array('products' => $products, 'title' => $title, 'filter' => $filter'));
```

to

```
View::make('home')->with(compact('products', 'title', 'filter'));
```

Comment: The drawback is that you IDE won't know that your are using those variables. So you'll end up with warnings about unused variables and messier automatic refactoring.

Comment: @Mediascreen : I use phpmd in my IDE (vim), and it seems to be compact aware. see https://github.com/manuelpichler/phpmd/blob/e8c3f53e7f419b68684352db1a4a4ffc5464a07e/src/test/php/PHPMD/Rule/UnusedLocalVariableTest.php#L497

Comment: @Mediascreen PhpStorm IDE recognizes the variables in `compact` method

Comment: The question was what is the benefit **over passing the actual variable**, so comparing it with an array makes no sense. You should be comparing it with `View::make('home')->with(compact($products, $title, $filter));` and explain the benefits of the string syntax over that one.

Comment: Passing a presenter-based DTO within the with() function would allow for more robust validation. The compact function is relatively unintelligent from this point of view - it's based and simple to implement, nothing else.

Answer (score 19):

`compact` is a function and not a language construct. There is no way for PHP functions to know the names of the variables passed to them. In theory, `compact` could be implemented as a language construct like `unset` or `isset` and work the way you described. But that's not what happened.

Comment: this is the actual answer to the question. if compact was a language construct then it could work, similar to how ES6 simplified this `{name: name, lastName: lastName}` into this: `{name, lastName}`

Comment: it may be correct, but compact would not have access to the caller scope if it was a normal function as well