# compact() vs manual array declaration on PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am usually using `compact()` function of php for the building array from the variables. Also, I can create that array manually. Are there any pros or cons of those usages? I am sharing an examples both of those declarations on the following segment:

**Compact Usage**

```
   <?php 
    $name = "John";
    $surname = "Doe";
    compact('name','surname');
?>
```

**Output:**

```
['name'=>'John','surname'=>'Doe']
```

---

**Manual Array Declaration**

```
<?php 
$name = "John";
$surname = "Doe";
$data = array("name"=>$name,"surname"=>$surname);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
['name'=>'John','surname'=>'Doe']
```

Comment: But, on the performance side it might be an difference a little bit

Comment: @bl4cksta Unless you're doing it very frequently, the performance difference should be negligible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does PHP compact() use strings instead of actual variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319729/why-does-php-compact-use-strings-instead-of-actual-variables)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it's more a matter of preference.

### Uses

If I have a bunch of local variables declared, and I happen to want my array keys to be named the same way, `compact` is very helpful.

I don't find that to be the case very often though. Typically I'm defining an array that is more complex:

```
$array = [
    'foo' => $something->foo(),
    'bar' => $bar,
    'baz' => A_CONSTANT
];
```

To use `compact` here you'd have to define your variables `$foo` `$bar` and `$baz` first, which seems silly.

I like `compact`, I just don't find it to be all around helpful most of the time.

### Performance

Ok I had to go do it. Here's a very basic non-scientific performance comparison:

https://3v4l.org/WTrOJ

In short, using `compact` is an order of magnitude slower.

And yet, you have to use it 100,000 (in this example) to matter a tiny fraction of a second.

In other words: use what makes the most sense for your code. Don't worry about the incredibly small performance difference!

Comment: I agree with "I just don't find it to be all around helpful most of the time.". I can also add that I have never seen compact be used in any useful manner, I have seen it abused to do things that are just wrong (like compacting variables so they are used to be passed as a parameter just to be expanded in another function).

Comment: Isn't your code less readable and less explicit if you use `compact`, how your IDE may work out the variable type if you use `compact` instead of a definition in array?

Comment: Could take the test results and make a click bait article titled "This function will have a 10-30x impact on your speed!" Sure it's only 2 ms vs .1ms for 100K loop.

Comment: "100,000... tiny fraction of a second." Try that for a public API where your code serve a million request each second. Usually there are some caches and such. But still...

Comment: I think Tomáš' answer illustrates pretty well why you shouldn't use compact in most cases. Static analysis can help you find quite a few bugs without testing, and using compact will cause false positives, which are at best annoying. That being said, there is nothing stopping static analysis tools from getting smarter in the future, in which case performance would be the only issue. Frankly I really like javascript's approach

Comment: @kaan_a Did you seriously downvote this 5 year-old answer? Whew! I said quite clearly "I just don't find it to be all around helpful." I absolutely agree it doesn't make sense in most cases. I still wanted to help the OP understand where someone _might_ use it, per the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. I did, however, upvote the other answer posted yesterday, which is probably why this question popped up on the front page and has gotten extra traffic. I think you were down voted because your answer is the accepted answer and the other one is better. I would recommend editing your answer to include the new information.

Comment: @kaan_a Nah. Static analysis wasn't as much of an option in 2016. This answer was spot on when it was posted. And now that there is another answer with the static info, wouldn't make sense to change this one.

Comment: The performance difference doesn't result from `compact` per se, rather, in your `compact` example you declare the variables separately, whilst in your array you simply assign strings directly. If you do `$array = [
        'foo' => $foo,
        'bar' => $bar,
        'baz' => $baz
    ];` you'll see that performance is near-identical: https://3v4l.org/e0Amo ... you may want to update your answer to reflect this. P.S. I like `compact`. Using it often where I have a range of methods that return an assoc. array with standard indexes (with local variable names matching said indexes).

Answer (score 31):

## 2021 Static Analysis Answer

The `compact()` used to be a handy shortcut for printing array of variables.
Yet nowadays, when we have PHPStan, Rector, IDE and strict types in PHP, using compact brings a huge obstacle for static analysis and IDE autocomplete.

Using explicit variables (2.) empowers your IDE and other tool to **know the types** and helps you with code autocompletion, static analysis and automated refactoring.

### 1. Using `compact()`

```php
function getValues(...) {
    $name = 'Elon';
    $surname = 'Musk';
    return compact('name','surname');
}

$items = getValues();
```

#### How does IDE/PHPStan/Rector see it?

- it's a function
- there are 2 strings
- return type of `getValues()` is `mixed[]`
- there are 2 unused variables - `$name` and `$surname`

```php
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $item->? // it's mixed
}
```

### 2. Using Explicit variables

```php
function getValues(...) {
    $name = 'Elon';
    $surname = 'Musk';

    return [
        'name' => $name,
        'surname' => $surname,
    ]);
}

$items = getValues();
```

#### How does IDE/PHPStan/Rector see it?

- it's an array
- there are 2 items
- return type of `getValues()` is `array<string, string>`

```php
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $item->? // it's a string
}
```

### Compare PHPStan results Yourself

- explicit: https://phpstan.org/r/48f4ce8b-c964-4a06-b03f-c182fb2d487f
- compact: https://phpstan.org/r/8023498a-b4fc-40e0-9086-36adafa1b2e3

[image]

Comment: I don't use PHPStan, but wouldn't you want `var_dump($values['unknown'])` to bark at you?

Comment: compact() is PHP since PHP 4. I don't think the support for this is comming to IDEs or static analyzers. Also it's a clear sign the language feature is crossing line of practical usability.