# Error in Laravel 5.6.9 while trying to display view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to display data in my views in Laravel 5.6.9, but I keep getting this error.

**Error**

[image: laravel 5.6.9 error]

**Code snippet**

[image]

**TodosController**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use\App\Todo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TodosController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $todos = Todo::all();
        return view('todos')->with('todos', '$todos');

    } 
}
```

Browser gave this error

```
<div class="title m-b-md">
    <?php $__currentLoopData = $todos; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $todo): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
    <?php echo e($todo->todo); ?>
<br>
```

Comment: can you show your controller code or what is in $todos ?

Comment: Please don't post your errors and code as image.

Comment: added my todoscontroller image up there, thanks

Comment: remove single quotes for $todos on todoscontroller line no 15.

Comment: return view('todos')->with('todos', $todos);

Comment: after `use` you dont need backslash , `use App\Todo;`

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, you must remove the single quotes around the `$todos` variable:

```
return view('todos')->with('todos', $todos);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your controller code like:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Todo;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TodosController extends Controller 
{ 
  public function index() { 

    $todos = Todo::get(); 
    return view('todos',compact('todos'));

  } 
}
```

Comment: @Toluwase: Thanks for upvote. Feel free to accept this as answer if our solution addressed your concern.

Comment: You used another way to send variables to the view than OP used, instead of just correcting his mistake. Can you explain, why using `compact(..)` istead of `->with(..)` is better? Otherwise this is not really helpful ;)

Comment: @Cashbee: Please review this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319729/why-does-php-compact-use-strings-instead-of-actual-variables)

Comment: No I mean you actually use another method to pass variables to the view. `view('todos', ['todos' => $todos])` is different from `view('todos')->with('todos', $todos)`. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views)

Answer (score 0):

A wiser approach to the situation would be to use compact. Compact is a PHP function that creates an array containing variables and their values.

When returning a view, we can easily use compact to pass some data.

One can use compact like this:

```
$data = Data::all();
return view('viewname')->with(compact('data'));
```

So in your script:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use\App\Todo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TodosController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $todos = Todo::all();
        return view('todos')->with(compact('todos'));

    } 
}
```

If you wish to do it the way you tried it in the first place, you should do it like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use\App\Todo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TodosController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $todos = Todo::all();
        return view('todos')->with('todos', $todos);

    } 
}
```

Mind that there are no apostrophes around the variable $todos.